# FPGA How to test desing

Tags: xilinx, vivado

I have a XAUI-Core and want to send Testframes over it to my Network card = NIC.

[image: whole concept]

- I have a little pattern generator, realized as processes.
- The simulation is "ok":  Pattern are sent to XAUI on xgmii_txd/ txc lines

**Current questions:**

- Question1 [solved] how clock my pattern generator processes
- Question2: how to reach my Network card

**Question 1 clocking**
[solved: using xaui clk output]

- When I connected the external refclk_p to XAUI-core and the
  processes, it didn't work.
- When only XAUI is connected to the external refclk_p and processes are connected with the "own" XAUI clk156 I can finally generate a Bitstream

Why?

[image: concept]

**Here is my XAUI Configuration:**
[image: xaui config shared logic]

It needs refclk_n & refclk_p for its transceivers:

```
->| IBUFDFS_GTE2|->refclk-> GTPE2_COMMON -> GTPE2_CHANNELs
->|             |
```

[image: ARTIX Pinout]
[image]
It says: **I and IB should be driven by IBUFs**

How should I connect refclk_n and refclk_p to my Design inputs?

[image: hwo should i connect refclk]

**Update**
I checked the datasheet and per accident I saw the **xgmii_txd** entrance of the XAUI-Core. It runs with **clk156_out**.

[image: xgmii_txd diagram]

I also checked how Xilinx did it with their testbench and example design:

[image: example design and testbench connection of clk156]

**Question 2: How to reach my Network Card**

**Sending Frames correctly **

do I need also wait 0.1 s for sending my testpattern? They do it in the testbench.

[image: simulation diagram]

- When I force a constant testpattern in the original Xilinx testbench
  simulation the XAUI output behaves like it "should".
- Normally XAUI lanes are not human readable.
- but there is a **monitor** in the testbench which translates it back
  to XGMII! Check this out i force 12345678912345678 into xgmii_txd and
  the XAUI output is same :D
- I could first test just a constant XGMII signal...  don't know what
  my phy does with this xD whill he provide it to my network card?
- will I see something in wireshark?

Current files:

**xdc file:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the GTE block has hardware defined specific pins that MUST be used for its clock input, I cannot tell if that 156MHz clock is wired to the right physical pins.

generally attempts to route between transceiver clock input pins and the general clock plane, never mind the fabric will fail, which is why the CLK156_OUT signal is available from the XAUI block (That is routable using normal clock plane).
Usually even with a standard LVDS clock input or such you get ONE ibufds per clock input pair, you can split the output side of the buffer but not the input.

> [Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG.
> If this sub optimal condition is acceptable for this design, you may
> use the CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE constraint in the .xdc file to demote
> this message to a WARNING. However, the use of this override is highly
> discouraged. These examples can be used directly in the .xdc file to
> override this clock rule.
> < set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets a7_mgt216_clk_p_i_IBUF] >

Seems to me to be saying that you are attempting to clock some other doings off the 216MHz input pin, yea, not going to work.
What you should be doing is clocking the rest of the business off the clk156_out from the XAUI core.

Comment: hi, thank you a lot for your answer. Haha yes yesterday I also did this and my design ran through IMPLEMENTAION step and a bitstream was generated "successfully". 1.) I need to check again what you wrote. 2.) I want to understand why I cant just take the original clock from entrance for my rising_edge() . I mean why not xD.. 3.) XAUI out is a bit time shifted from the refclk_p/ n.. but maybe it is not important for my processes-->I need to rethink :) Thank you :)

Comment: ok as far as I understand Xilinx also uses the clk156 for its stimulus. I posted the connection in my init post. Please check it :D

Comment: @t1fpga1 It has everything to do with the physical reality of an FPGA, those pins are (I assume) constrained as an LVDS or similar input, so will be expecting an IBUF_DS to be declared as the input receiver. Note that there is no routing between the input pin(s) and the IBUF, this is a physical entity that exists as part of the input IOB tile, see UG571 (For the ultrascale version, but it is much the same) specifically the diagram on page 19.  You get to declare ONE IBUF* or IOBUF* per pin or pin pair, because it is all shared hardware in the IOB.

Comment: Testbeches are in general not synthesisable, and certainly nothing  with wait used to implement a delay will be. That 0.1ns looks to me to be trying to play games with delta cycles or something, it is purely a simulation thing, in syntheesisable code you would just be doing 'if rising_edge (clk156)....'

Comment: yeah someone told me already that 0.1 ns is not that important.But I don't know 100%. As long as the design runs stable I don't care :) I even saw I can put in a constant value and it will be translated by the xaui. Maybe my phy gets some data and so my NIC.